# Get Multiple RadioButton Values into one TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's imagine, I have a couple of different boxes, each box has multiple `RadioButtons`. When user selects the `RadioButton` from box1, box 2, box3, etc. the selected values from all `RadioButtons` are entered into on `TextBox`. E.g. A selected in box 1, 24 selected in box2, 20 selected in box3 - it should give the following: A 24 20 or A - 24 - 20. I have tried with the following code for each `RadioButton` but it only enters a value from one `RadioButton` at the time. Thank you in advance

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked) //If checked == true
{
   textBox1.Text = "12";
   //example
}
```

Comment: Seems like this helped: textBox1.Text += rdbtn.Text; however, when I do a correction and check different radiobox, the previously selected value is kept in textbox and newly selected one is added; it does not replace the previous one. Additionally, having space between all characters would be great.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Text of all checked radio buttons this way:

```
var radios = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
                 .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
                 .Select(x => x.Text);

this.textBoxText1.Text = string.Join("-", radios);
```

If the order of returned result is not desired, you can order the group boxes based on a property like `TabIndex` or `Name` using `this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x=>x.TabIndex)` then the result would be in desired order.

Comment: You can use such linq query to get desired result.

Comment: Finally I have implemented this code and it is exactly what I needed, cheers. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just setting the `.Text` property of your `TextBox` simply concatenate your strings to it using the `+=` operator.

Example:

`textBox1.Text += "12";`